# Discord.py "missing 1 required positional argument: 'coro'"

Tags: python, discord.py

Im trying to use the missingpermissions module with discord.py. But im getting the error "missing 1 required positional argument: 'coro'". Im not sure why this is happening. This is the full code

```py
@client.command()
@has_permissions(manage_roles=True, kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await member.kick(reason=reason)

@kick.error()
async def kick_error(error, ctx, ):
    if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions):
        text = "Sorry {}, you do not have permissions to do that!".format(ctx.message.author)
        await client.send_message(ctx.message.channel, text)
```

And the code that is causing the issues is this

```py
@kick.error()
async def kick_error(error, ctx, ):
    if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions):
        text = "Sorry {}, you do not have permissions to do that!".format(ctx.message.author)
        await client.send_message(ctx.message.channel, text)
```

Especially the `python @kick.error` part.

And the error message is this

```py
   @kick.error()
TypeError: error() missing 1 required positional argument: 'coro'
```

Comment: Hello @Pixler, and welcome to StackOverflow! Please include a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and the *full text* of the error (starting with "Traceback (most recent call last):") since that contains a lot of information.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no parenthesis in the error decorator:

```py
@kick.error
async def kick_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions):
        text = "Sorry {}, you do not have permissions to do that!".format(ctx.message.author)
        await ctx.respond(text)
```

Also, the `ctx` comes first and `error` should be the second argument.
You can find all of this information in the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html#error-handling).

NB: You can use fstrings instead of `format`:

```py
text = f"Sorry {ctx.message.author}, you do not have permissions to do that!"
```

Comment: Im now getting this error.

```
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'send_message'
```

Comment: That's the old way of sending messages, you can read this [article](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html) to see all the changes. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: I need help again. Im geting this error "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\User\Downloads\DiscordServer Bot\PaddsIslandServer.py", line 76, in <module>
    @kick.error
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'error'
Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x0000014527E677F0>
PS C:\Users\User\Downloads\DiscordServer Bot> "

Comment: Is `client` a `commands.Bot` instance? If not, it should be.